# What is a proper way to store comments in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

I'm thinking how to design comments. My initial idea was just to store a Comments list in a document:

```
public class BlogPost
{
   ...
   public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

But I need to implement voting so I'd like to have an identificator for each comment (to find out which comment was voted at the client). But RavenDb is not very friendly for nested objects identificators.

So I am confused whether should I fake Comment identificator or store comments in a more relational way:

```
public class Comment
{
  public string BlogPostId {get;set;}
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public IList<CommentVote> Votes {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up identifying comments with AuthorId + CreationDateTime